# Acces Azure Synapse from Databricks using system managed identity

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I'm following this guide:
https://joeho.xyz/blog-posts/how-to-connect-to-azure-synapse-in-azure-databricks/
to connect to Azure Synapse from Databricks. Specificaly I'm stuck on this part:

```
# Azure Synapse Connection Configuration
dwDatabase = <<your-database-name>>
dwServer = <<your-sql-sever-name>>
dwUser = <<your-database-account>>
dwPass = <<your-database-account-password>>
dwJdbcPort =  "1433"
dwJdbcExtraOptions = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
sqlDwUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{dwServer}:{dwJdbcPort};database={dwDatabase};user={dwUser};password={dwPass};${dwJdbcExtraOptions}"
```

Problem is I can't use user and password, I can only connect through system managed identity. How do I do this?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: The Spark driver can [connect to Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#spark-driver-to-azure-synapse) using these two authentications 1) JDBC with a username and password. 2) OAuth 2.0 with a service principal for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Databricks clusters doesn't have managed identity, so you can't do it right now.  As of right now, the only supported options are either username + password, or service principal with OAuth.  See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#--authentication) for more details.