# Get Azure managed identity token from Databricks using Python

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-databricks

I am trying to get a token for a managed identity account from Databricks using Python. Is it even possible from Databricks? If so, can you please suggest a code idea using Python/PySpark from Databricks?

The end goal is to connect to a SQL server from Databricks using Managed Identity.

Comment: Currently, Databricks does not support reading SQL with managed identity though I have not seen documentation clearly stating this. The next safest option is to use a Service principal with certificates. Have a look at this blog. https://medium.com/@anupamchand/integrate-databricks-to-sql-with-msal-using-secret-and-certificates-b8f36ad06a11

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915547/acces-azure-synapse-from-databricks-using-system-managed-identity/73933465#73933465 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72799562/is-it-possible-to-connect-sql-server-using-object-id-from-azure-managed-identity/72801795#72801795